# Use a different notification sound for events and replies in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Currently, chat event notifications and direct replies in chat produce the same sound effect. I think those two are different enough that they should be distinguishable by their sound effect alone.

The main reason this would be useful for me is that chat replies and @notifications are something that I actually want to be notified about. Event notifications on the other hand are like a plague that you catch when visiting the wrong chat room (e.g. because of a flag), and that you won't get rid off quickly not matter what you do.

And even if you actually care about the even notifications, being able to distinguish between those different types of notifications without having to look at the chat page would be useful.